# How do I convert a WriteableBitmap into a BitmapImage object in Silverlight5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

How do I convert a WriteableBitmap into a BitmapImage object in Silverlight5 ?

So far, here is my attempt in converting a WriteableBitmap into a BitmapImage; however, it doesn't work.

No exception is thrown, the resulting BitmapImage is simply an 'empty' object with no data; both PixelHeight and PixelWidth are zero:

```
public BitmapImage Convert(WriteableBitmap wb)
{
   int[] p = wb.Pixels;
   int len = p.Length * 4;
   byte[] result = new byte[len];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, result, 0, len);

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result);

   BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
   bi.SetSource(ms); 

   // bi.PixelHeight and bi.PixelWidth are zero.

   return bi; // pretty much an empty image.
}
```

Cross-post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/0a0c833b-8e68-4c8d-871a-d0805d84ba16/writeablebitmap-to-bitmapimage?forum=silverlightpivotviewer

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to convert from `WriteableBitmap` to `BitmapImage`? Both are subclasses of `BitmapSource` and can thus be assigned to for example an `Image` element via `Image.Source`.

Comment: Anders, this is why I need a BitmapImage: The Silverlight5 PivotViewer control only accepts binding to a BitmapImage object to display its 'tiles'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion on your cross-post:

Yes, you have to convert your image to either png or jpg to create a `BitmapImage`.

The stream the `BitmapImage` expects is an encoded image file, but the bytes you get from `WriteableBitmap` is an uncompressed, raw ARGB pixel format.

In order to produce either a png or a jpg you have to use either link against a library that can do this, or use Stegman's one-page png encoder (that doesn't actually compress anything).

Since this was already suggested in the forum you asked but you noticed that the link is broken, I put a public [gist on github](http://gist.github.com/jtheisen/8547098) from the copy I had locally.

Comment: John, thank you for the link; I further appreciate how you've explained the underlying issue.